# How does ESP8266 work as web server with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am trying to learn internet of things with smart home. I will connect an ESP8266 and an Arduino with the IBM Bluemix server to control a circuit from a public IP.

I want to start with the local network for now. I have gone through a couple of links which seem like a great start http://allaboutee.com/2014/12/30/esp8266-and-arduino-webserver/

They explain how it works, and have source code but no circuit diagram. How should I connect the ESP8266 with Arduino for this example ?

[image]

[image]

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 2; // Wire this to Tx Pin of ESP8266
const byte txPin = 3; // Wire this to Rx Pin of ESP8266

// We'll use a software serial interface to connect to ESP8266
SoftwareSerial esp8266(rxPin,txPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Sending an AT commands");
  esp8266.println("AT");
  delay(30);
  while(esp8266.available()) {
    String data = esp8266.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println("Got response from esp8266: " + data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same way as any other ESP8266 example. The fact that you are using it as a web server doesn't change how you wire it.

For that specific code snippet it even tells you in the comments:

```
// make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
// This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
// and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
```

Comment: In case of `ESP8266` act as web server, can we connect TX/RS of `ESP8200` to any digital pins of arduino ?

Comment: Like I said: the fact you're using it as a web server makes absolutely no difference to how you wire it. It's using SoftwareSerial. SoftwareSerial will work on any pins. Take your pick.

Comment: I have this code https://pastebin.com/1miy33ne but esp is not sending a message as this condition `while(esp8266.available()) {` always fails

Comment: I have added my pictorial representation of my project in question

Comment: How about power? How about ground? How about the other pins that are required to make the ESP8266 work? Every single Arduino tutorial for the ESP8266 shows you those.

Comment: I see. Thanks for giving hint. Lemme try :)

Comment: Another hint: Do a google image search for "ESP8266 Arduino". You will get thousands of pictures showing you how to wire it.

Comment: Yup, trying to do same..